# Арканоид на c++

Tags: c++, математика, геометрия, физика

Задали написать арканоид. Возникла проблема с моментом физики поведения мяча, мяч и дощечка ( от которой он отскакивает ) представляют собой структуры с координатами, цветом и радиусом. Сама рабочая область уже написана, но пока что не очень понимаю как конкретно реализовать физику

Comment: Взять *параметрическое уравнение линии*. Задать вектор движения, после удара - пересчитывать вектор.

Comment: А как рассчитать начальный угол запуска, то есть если его просто запустит не двигая планку то он просто вертикально полетит, а если двигать ею до запуска то она должна запуститься с иным углом, как вот именно зависит этот угол от скорости движения доски при запуске

Comment: Если можель - радиус-угол, и угол в радианах - то вам одна из функций - arcsin arccos arctan. (При извесных параметрах треугольника вектора в декартовой системе).

Comment: А тут физика не нужна, можно вручную задать соотношение скоростей отражения скоростям падания.

Comment: Есть другой метод - задать dx, dy и менять их местами и/или менять знаки - так проще.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую, если что отпишусь, спасибо!